# How to set data and log file location for SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, windows

I'm trying to create a database where the data and log files are saved to the E drive but not sure how to do so. I've tried:

> CREATE DATABASE TachographDataContent_Archive
>   [ON E:\MySqlDir\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data]
>   [LOG ON {D:\MySqlDir\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data}]

And I'm getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'TachographDataContent_Archive'.

Answer (score 1):

To create database using query, you need to mention .mdf and .ldf file. So try below script.

Like this

```
CREATE DATABASE [TachographDataContent_Archive]  
ON  PRIMARY (NAME = 'TachographDataContent', FILENAME = 'E:\MySqlDir\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\TachographDataContent.mdf')
LOG ON 
(NAME = 'TachographDataContent_log', FILENAME = 'E:\MySqlDir\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\TachographDataContent_log.ldf')
GO
```

good luck...

Comment: thank you, im now getting this error: 
Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "E:\MySqlDir\MSSQL.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\TachographDataContent.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Do you think I just have the wrong path name maybe?

Comment: @user3478524 : This error comes because you have to first create folder **MySqlDir** and so on in your "E:" drive.